# converting a string into a raw float number

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to take out the floating numbers of a string and get them raw like for example: `"temp=33.3'c"`
and the other answers I got didn't put out raw like this: `33.3`
instead it came out like: `['33.3']`
(one of the ones I used that did put out raw but it only worked with a spaced out string):

```
s = "temp= 49.4 'C" #spaced out or it wont work

for i in s.split():
try:

    result = float(i)

    break
except:
    continue

print(result)
```

It just outputs an error.

The main code I'm working on:

```
import os

cmd = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').read()
s = cmd
res = int(i) for i in test_string.split() if i.isdigit()
print(res)


celsius = list(res)`

fahrenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32
print('%0.1f degree Celsius is equal to %0.1f degree Fahrenheit' %(celsius,fahrenheit))
```

I need something that can read the string without it having to be spaced out AND output it as a raw float number.

Comment: I'm really confused by this code. What is the point of `s = cmd`? `res = int(i) for i in test_string.split() if i.isdigit()` isn't valid - it's not a comprehension of any kind. I can't even work out whether you're trying to handle user input or a file

Comment: You should show us what the error message.

Comment: if you are tying to get the number and have problem go with regex something like `[0-9]+\.[0-9]` but this will need you to input a dot and number ex: **35.0** works while **35** does not. also to get the temperature type try `[0-9]+\.[0-9]|[c|C]|[f|F]` this will find also the letter than you will have to split it. `temp = re.findall('[0-9]+\.[0-9]|[c|C]|[f|F]', "My temperature is 35.3 C")`

Comment: Why not use: `[0-9.]` since he's just trying to capture the numerical value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `s = "temp=49.4'C"`, you can do this a couple different ways:

Splitting:

```
print(float(s.split('=')[1].split('\'')[0]))
```

Regular expression:

```
import re
print(float(re.match("^temp=(.*)'C$", s).group(1)))
```

Comment: import os


cmd = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').read()
s = cmd

celsius = (float(s.split('=')[1].split('\'')[0]))


fahrenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32
print('%0.1f degree Celsius is equal to %0.1f degree Fahrenheit' %(celsius,fahrenheit))



this is the finished code i made it so that anyone could use it thank you for helping me finish it. this code is used for the raspberry pi. it takes the temperature and converts it to the american Fahrenheit.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is because indentation.

Your code should be like that:

```
s = "temp= 49.4 'C" #spaced out or it wont work
for i in s.split():                            
    try:                                       
        result = float(i)                      
    except:                                    
        pass                                   

print(result)
```

Or try:

```
s = "temp= 49.4 'C"
result=float(s.split()[1])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a number within any string string use this:

```
import re
print(float(re.search("([\d\.]+)", s).group(1)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the following code gives the same result as you expect.

```
s = "temp=49.4C" 
ans=""
def split(word):
    return list(word)

for i in split(s):
    try:
        if(i=="."):
            ans+=i
    else:
        j=float(i)
        ans+=i
except:
        continue
print(float(ans))
```

Comment: Why have you created a function called `split` when it's a builtin? And it's more sophisticated than what you've just redefined it as

Comment: As far as I know the built-in split function does not split a string with no spaces. The query also required to have the input string no spaces.